# How to mock a method inside Express router Jest test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express, jestjs

I'm trying to test a router in Node.js app with Jest + Supertest, but my router is making a call to service, which is calling the endpoint:

```js
router.post('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;

    // I WANT TO MOCK userService.getUserInfo FUNCTION, BECAUSE IT IS MAKING A POST CALL
    const identity = await userService.getUserInfo(username, password);

    if (!identity.authenticated) {
      return res.json({});
    }

    const requiredTenantId = process.env.TENANT_ID;
    const tenant = identity.tenants.find(it => it.id === requiredTenantId);

    if (requiredTenantId && !tenant) {
      return res.json({});
    }

    const userResponse = {
      ...identity,
      token: jwt.sign(identity, envVars.getVar(envVars.variables.AUTH_TOKEN_SECRET), {
        expiresIn: '2h',
      }),
    };

    return res.json(userResponse);
  } catch (err) {
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

This is my test that works well:

```js
test('Authorized - respond with user object', async () => {
  const response = await request(app)
    .post('/api/user/login')
    .send(users.authorized);
  expect(response.body).toHaveProperty('authenticated', true);
});
```

this is how `getUserInfo` function looks like:

```
const getUserInfo = async (username, password) => {
  const identity = await axios.post('/user', {username, password});

  return identity;
}
```

but it executes the method `getUserInfo` inside a router and this method is making a REST call - I want to mock this method in order to avoid REST calls to other services.
How it could be done?

I've found a **mockImplementation** function in Jest docs https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockimplementationfn

but how I can mock func inside a supertest testing?

Comment: I guess that you start a "real" api server before these tests, that means that your tests are running in a different node context (separate process), therefore there is no why that tests can mock something in it.
Am I right?

Comment: I've added `getUserInfo` to the description

Comment: I want to mock this function in order not to make calls to external API

Comment: Is my assumption is correct? you start an API server & run the tests?

Comment: no, 'API server' is the external service

Comment: Ok, does my explanation make sense to you?

Comment: Helpful question, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use jest's auto mocking at the top of your test

like so:

```
jest.mock('./path/to/userService');

// and include it as well in your test
const userService = require('./path/to/userService');
```

it will generate a mock of the entire module and every function will be replaced with `jest.fn()` with no implementation

and then depending on the userService if it's just an object it's `getUserInfo` method will be a jest.fn() and you can set it's return value like this:

```
// resolved value as it should return a promise
userService.getUserInfo.mockResolvedValue(mockIdentity);
```

and the mockIdentity will have to look something like this:

```
const mockIdentity = {
      authenticated: true,
      tenants: [
        {
          id: "x12",
          mockInfo: "mock-info-value"
        }
      ],
      mother: "Superwoman",
      father: "Superman"
    })
  }
```

Comment: thank you very much! but where exactly I should place `userService.getUserInfo.mockResolvedValue(mockIdentity);`? I'm using `supertest` request with its syntax: `(request(...).post(...).send(...))`

Comment: @Karen before initiating the request `request(...).post(...).send(...)`

Comment: I'm receiving an error:
```expect(received).toHaveProperty(path, value)

    Expected path: "authenticated"
    Received path: []

    Expected value: true
    Received value: {"error": "Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"}```
will try to fix it and let you know about the results

Comment: it is responding with empty object, not `mockidentity` obj

Comment: I have a similar scenario, except my `fetch` call is in a middleware that eventually populates the request object based on the response. Did this work for you @Karen

Comment: @Teneff helpful answer. Thanks.